# Refactor my data reader to work with multiple tables

Tags: c#

How can I improve this method so that it works with multiple tables?

```
   public void ExecuteStoredProcedure(string StoredProcedureName)
   {
       using (var connection = new SqlConnection(provider.ConnectionString))
       {
           using (var command = new SqlCommand(StoredProcedureName, connection))
           {
               command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
               using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
               {
                   while (reader.Read())//problem is here
                   {
                       Console.WriteLine(reader[0].ToString());
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

I could return the reader (but I think that means I'd have to drop my using statements).  Or, I could create a factory that processes each table depending on a parameter that I add to the ExecuteStoredProcedure().  Or whatever.

How can I get the reader functionality outta here?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish; but I wouldn't modify your code at all (other than maybe returning the results rather that writing to the console).  I'm not sure what the benefit would be, and as you mentioned, the downside would be the possibility not having the IDisposables properly disposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SqlDataReader.NextResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult.aspx). Have a look at article - [How To Handle Multiple Results by Using the DataReader in Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311274)